# boot one laptop from another?

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, bios, pxe

*I don't want to install or format anything.*

Rather than booting laptop `alpha` from a thumb drive, how would I boot it from laptop `beta`?  The notion is for `beta` to mount `alpha`.  Rather than a thumb drive, just using an actual laptop, `beta`.

I've looked at [Diskless Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto), [Netboot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot),[PXE Install Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer) but aren't quite sure which of these apply.

Would USB make a difference compared to ethernet?

Similar to, but distinct from, mounting a second hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if you are installing or just booting , i'm going to assume you want to boot an installer.

as you can see from the instructions PXE booting is complex an time consuming, its really only suited for situations where you have many hosts and many oses.

making a bootable usb device is really the easiest and safest way.

this could be a usb stick or you could try a custom usbA to usbA cable and 
making one of your usb ports work as usb-gadget presenting a storage class device, http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/. This is what embedded devices often do to facilitate firmware updates.

you could also just remove the hdd drive from alpha and put it in beta but it will still need some adjustments to make it work.

Comment: I suppose you can't boot one laptop from another with USB if only because there's not nearly enough power?

Comment: no its the relationship thats a problem , usb interfaces are host or device , host to host isn't supported. the usb gadget class is a workaround for this, i've updated my answer